# How do I install json-p for intellij?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

What I need is a link and how to do it. I tried downloading one, but it gave me a file. It’s confusing because it’s not a jar file. It’s just a file with the classes and stuffs in them. I want to get the json in a way I can import it. (Like how I’ll import scanner and other stuffs.)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFpy9.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try to explain more in depth what you are trying to accomplish.
But that looks like a **Maven Dependency**.
Read up on how to create a Maven Project and add json-p dependency.
When you create your project, add this to your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jsonp</groupId>
    <artifactId>providers</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-RC3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```